# How to convert scad files to stl?

Tags: 3d, cad, openscad

I am trying to export scad files from OpenSCAD to STL. I keep getting an error:

> Current top level object is not a 3d model.

If it's not a 3d model, how do I convert it to 3d model If I know the dimensions?

The source is located at https://github.com/hugs/bitbeam

Answer (score 1):

the `projection()` call makes it a 2D object. remove this line and the last `}`

```
use <arduino.scad>

beam_width = 7.9375;   // 5/16 inches

projection(){        // <------ REMOVE THIS
    difference(){

        // Base plate
        cube([8*9, beam_width * 9, 1]);

        // Bottom row
        for (x=[8 : 8 : beam_width * 10]) {
            translate([x-4, beam_width/2, -10])
            cylinder(r=2.4, h=20, $fn=25);
        }

        // Top row
        for (x=[8 : 8 : beam_width * 10]) {
            translate([x-4, (beam_width/2) + beam_width * 8, -10])
            cylinder(r=2.4, h=20, $fn=25);
       }

        translate([17,60,0]) MountingHoles();
    }
} // <----------- REMOVE THIS

// Uncomment next line if you want to see the entire board
//translate([17,60,2]) Arduino();
```